# vcl.net to delphi prism

Tags: .net, delphi, vcl, delphi-prism, oxygene

i have some vcl.net apps(delphi 2006 , .net 1.1 ) and i like to port them to delphi.net 2007 .
but i like to port it to delphi prism as it has mono support so i can port it on liux and support to latest .net framework(but i know mono supports full .net 1.1),as prism is completely new and vcl is deprecated how to upgrade my app to prism. i am not ready to change each and every line,and the project is very big also , i use jvcl olso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ShineOn](http://code.remobjects.com/p/shineon/) library as a replacement for some parts of the VCL.NET.

You can translate Delphi syntax to Delphi Prism syntax with [Oxidizer](http://code.remobjects.com/p/oxidizer/).

Both are projects from RemObjects software (the company behind the compiler and IDE integration of Delphi Prism).

They are both only aids though, so your mileage will still vary.